# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' at line 2

Tags: php

Unfortunately my start was not very good at the time. But this time I have PHP Code problem.

This code is available. In line 2 with "<" it means that it can not be parsed. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php if (!wp_is_mobile()) {
   <div id="content">
                <!-- Posts anzeigen -->
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <!-- Datumsheader -->
                        <p class="dateheader"><?php the_date('l, j. F Y'); ?></p>
                    <!-- Posttitel -->
                        <a class="posttitle" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        </a>
                    <!-- Posttext -->
                        <div class="entry">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <p style="text-align:right;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#comments" title="Kommentare zu '<?php the_title(); ?>'"><?php comments_number('Noch kein Kommentar','1 Kommentar','%Kommentare'); ?></a></p>
                        <hr class="postende" />
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <!-- Posts anzeigen Ende-->

                <!-- aeltere und neuere Posts anzeigen / Seitennavigation -->
                    <p align="center">
                    <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo;Neuere Eintr&auml;ge') ?> | 
                    <?php next_posts_link('&Auml;ltere Eintr&auml;ge &raquo;') ?>
                    </p><!-- Seitennavigation Ende -->

            <?php endif; ?>
            <hr />
        </div>
            <div id="footer1">
                <div id="spalte1">
                    <h3>Suche</h3>
                    <p>
                    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                       <input type="text" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars($s, 1); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
                       <input type="submit" id="search_submit" value="Suchen" />
                    </form>
                    </p>
                    <h3>ganzjährige Blogprojekte</h3>
                    <p>
                        <a href="http://tweedandgreet.de/12coloursofhandmadefashion/" target="_blank">12 Colors of Handmade Fashion</a>  (jeden Monat eine Farbe, zu der genäht werden darf) <br />
                        <a href="http://die-photographin.de/2016/12/increase-creativity-challenge-2017/" target="_blank">Increase Infinity</a> (jeden Monat eine Farbe, zu der gebloggt werden soll)<br />
                        <a href="https://vom-landleben.de/blogprojekt/fotoprojekt17/" target="_blank">Fotoprojekt17</a> (jeden         Monat ein Thema, zu dem fotografiert werden kann)<br />
                        <a href="https://tonari.wordpress.com/category/rost-parade/" target="_blank">Fotoprojekt: Rostparade</a> (immer am letzten Tag des Monats Rostfotos online stellen) <br />
                        <a href="http://fuenfzig-millimeter.de/projekt-graustufe-allgemeine-informationen/" target="_blank">Fotoprojekt: Graustufen</a> (jeden Monat ein Thema, zu dem Schwarz-weiß-Fotos gemacht werden sollen)<br />
                        <a href="https://heutemachtderhimmelblau.com/bunt-ist-die-welt/" target="_blank">Fotoprojekt: Bunt ist die Welt</a> (Jeden Sonntag ein Thema, zu dem für fünf Tage fotografiert werden darf)<br />
                        <a href="http://kathastrophal.de/aus-diyyourcloset-wird-naehdirwas" target="_blank">Näh dir was</a> (Jeden Monat ein neues Nähthema, zu dem man etwas für sich nähen soll)<br />
                        <a href="http://www.whatinaloves.com/2017/01/bloggerproject-lets-cook-together-2017.html" target="_blank">Lets cook toghether</a> (Jeden Monat ein Thema, zu dem gekocht/gebacken und ab dem 10. Tag des Monats verlinkt werden darf)<br />
                        <a href="http://www.tastesheriff.com/die-gemuese-expedition/" target="_blank">Die Gemüse-Expedition</a> (Jeden Monat ein Gemüse, das in der Küche verarbeitet werden soll)<br />

                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="spalte2">
                    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar() ) : ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <div id="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

} ?><!-- Ende Destop -->
        <div id="sidebar">
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?><!-- sucht sidebar.php und fügt den Code hier ein -->
        </div>
        <div id="footer2"><?php get_footer(); ?><!-- sucht footer und fügt den Code hier ein --></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I own hardly any programmer knowledge and the code output would like to realize a forum user with me.

I hope you can help me so.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The easiest way to resolve syntax errors is to delete things until they go away, then carefully restore bits of code until they re-emerge. I hope you're using a version control system to track your changes, that makes this process even more efficient. It's also a good idea to have a syntax-highlighting editor, it can usually call out mistakes in a way that's difficult to overlook.

Comment: @tadman, it would be much more effective to move around a `exit;` statement to see if you code runs up to that point.

Comment: @Jeppesen Also a good idea. There's a few tricks that can save a ton of time.

Comment: @tadman, Thanks for the tip. This wrong code had me a user of my forum showed. I myself work with the Phase 5 editor.

I have a version control system but in the Github repositories of mine. In PHP, I do not even program anything, but I deal with it sometimes when the need exists.

Comment: Sounds like you've got all the right tools, so that's good.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close the PHP tag at line 2 before you start the HTML again

```
<?php if (!wp_is_mobile()) { ?>
```

and you forgot to open the PHP tag at line 67 ...

```
<?php
} 
?><!-- Ende Destop -->
```

In order to avoid this, make sure you have a good PHP IDE that has an integrated code syntax checker. It will point out right away when something as fundamental is missing

Comment: @ Patrick Simard,

Thanks for the great help. In advance, I checked the above PHP code with the online checkers and since I had assumed that which PHP tags are missing. Now I know more about it.

Comment: What do you use to compose your PHP code? You should take a look at PHPStorm. It will tell you as you compose that you forgot something important lol